# Increment a variable on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This seems like a very simple thing to do, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have:

```
<button id="more">more</button>
<button id="less">less</button>

<p id="info"></p>

<script>
var howMany = 1;
$(#more).click(function(){
    howMany + 1;
});
$(#less).click(function(){
    howMany - 1;
});
$("#info").text(howMany);
</script>
```

I simply want the info paragraph to increase or decrease when the user click more or less.

Comment: `howMany + 1;` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code, as others have already mentioned like missing quotes in selector, not reassigning variable value after incrementing/decementing.

```
var howMany = 1;
$('#more').click(function(){
    howMany += 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
$('#less').click(function(){
    howMany -= 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
$("#info").text(howMany);​
```

Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/eLVxn/)

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues:

- You need strings as selectors. So enclose `#more` with quotes: `"#more"`.
- You need to update the variable, not just calculate the addition or subtraction and ignore the result. Use `+=` and `-=` instead of `+` and `-`.
- You probably want to update the `<p>` element after every addition/subtraction. So put the `.text` call inside both click functions, after having updated the variable.

Comment: I saw the `howMany + 1;` but totally missed that the selector wasn't a string. Good eye!

Answer (score 1):

You add 1 to `howMany`, but don't affect the result to a variable.
Use `howMany = howMany + 1;` or `howMany += 1;`

EDIT : according to pimvdb answer, ther're other problems, have a look on his post.
Corrected code is here :

```
<button id="more">more</button>
<button id="less">less</button>

<p id="info"></p>

<script>
var howMany = 1;
$("#more").click(function(){
    howMany += 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
$("#less").click(function(){
    howMany -= 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the result to the variable, plus you're setting the `text` of the element **outside** the click event! Try:

```
$("#more").click(function(){
    howMany += 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
$("#less").click(function(){
    howMany -= 1;
    $("#info").text(howMany);
});
```